# Spark local mode on k8s

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, apache-spark-sql

I am running spark in local mode with local[*] option on k8s, where I have defined the k8s pod's cpu request and limit as 4 cores but when I am checking it's even touching 6 cores, how is it possible? Is there any way to control spark to use upto k8s provided cpu cores only i.e 4 cores in this case.